# I accidentally deleted Python 2.7 what do I do?

Tags: 16.04, unity, python, gnome-terminal, python-2.7

I accidentally deleted python 2.7 and now I can't use the gnome-terminal, Unity Tweak Tool, I can search them however I cant launch them, and I get an error message in the status bar on top saying "A problem occurred when checking for the updates" if I click show updates it doesn't do anything what do I do? Bear in mind I am very new to Linux and Ubuntu.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Press Control + ALT + F1 and login, and then type:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-minimal
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52301/discussion-on-answer-by-harris-i-accidentally-deleted-python-2-7-what-do-i-do).